# Who wrote Aleh Katan by Avraham Fried?

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, music

There is a (in my opinion) beautiful song by Avraham Fried called Aleh Katan. Does anyone know who composed this song?

Is it Yishai Lapitdot? It seems like he said his name here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmHrk1ZdVsQ&feature=related

Comment: Hmmm... Is this on topic? Does the song perhaps qualify as a piyyut?

Comment: Well, he definitely says "Yishai Lapidot—aizeh shir niflah." Seems to imply Lapidot either composed or arranged the song.

Comment: @Dave, I don't know the song. If it's a Jewish-life or Jewish-learning song, then I think this question is on-topic. Otherwise (like http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4994), not.

Comment: From the translation here (http://imamother.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1332753#1332753), I don't see anything particularly Jewish about it.

Comment: @Dave I always understood the song to be a parable for the Jew (or Jews).

Comment: @HodofHod if I find a Green Day song that I understand to be a parable of the Jews can I ask who wrote the lyrics? Or is Avraham Fried special cuz he sings in Hebrew whereas Billy Joe Armstrong sings in English?

Comment: @l'  That comparison is just slightly flawed, I think. I think you know why, but I'll be perfectly clear: Avraham Fried is an observant Jew, who sings songs written and composed by observant Jews. All of those songs are either explicitly or implicitly related to Jewish life and/or learning. Comes along one song which is obviously metaphorical, with the most obvious interpretation being Jewish life-related. I think it's pretty safe to say that Alei Katan is no exception to the rest of his music.

Comment: I can think of _many_ people who sing in Hebrew whose songs I wouldn't consider Jewish life-related, and many who sing in English who I would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a website named [www.hebrewsongs.com](http://www.hebrewsongs.com/?song=alehkatansheli), both the music and lyrics were composed by Ishai Lapidot.

According to [MostlyMusic.com](http://www.mostlymusic.com/aleh-katan-single.html), the song was arranged by Yuval Stupal.

Answer (score 0):

The song was compsed including the lyrics by Yishai Lapidot arranged by Yuval Stupal

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and welcome! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1375), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features. Also, since this answer is merely correcting a typo (in the spelling of "Yishai") to the preexisting answer, it would be better left as a comment on (or edit to) that answer than as a separate answer; once you stick around actively on the site long enough, you will be able to leave such comments and to edit others' answers.